# ros-jade-ros-tutorials not found

Tags: ros, debian, wheezy, ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, new user here.
I am trying to get ROS running on an Intel Edison.  I have it up and running after having installed it with the raspberry pi instructions.

However when I try to install the ROS tutorials it fails to find the package.

Is there a reason the tutorials would not install on this sort of minimal installation?  It is there on the full desktop install.

Here are the instructions I followed
http://martinkronberg.com/new-blog/2015/3/18/ros-on-intel-edison-using-ubilinux-and-porting-to-yocto
Which closely follow http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi

I adjusted the commands to install jade rather than indigo.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
The command and output is:

```
root@ubilinux:~# sudo apt-get install ros-jade-ros-tutorials
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-jade-ros-tutorials
```

content of ors-latest.list

```
root@ubilinux:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list 
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu wheezy main
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217433/ros-jade-ros-tutorials-not-found/) by [billtyler](https://answers.ros.org/users/23824/billtyler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-09-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-09-10**:
Please provide the actual commands you're running as well as the console output of the errors.

**Comment by [billtyler](https://answers.ros.org/users/23824/billtyler/) on 2015-09-10**:
added to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ahh, you're on wheezy. That's not a standard target platform, see [REP 3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#jade-turtle-may-2015-may-2017) for more specific targeted platforms.

There was a raspberry pi specific effort for raspbian which used wheezy debs. But that was specific to raspberry pi architecture. On the Intel Edison, if you install Ubuntu you can use the common debian packages. If you want to use wheezy you can try to shoehorn the ubuntu debs in (not guarenteed to work) or compile from source.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0